# Patenting existing product in a package of single unit

Tags: patentability, packaging

Is package of single unit of a known product patentable? 
 assuming that this product does not exists or sold in a single unit. also this product currently sold to organizations and companies and not in the retail stores.

For example (and this example already exists but lets say it doesn't):
Toothpicks are sold in pack of 100-200 units. and i want to patent a toothpick packed as a single unit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be patentable, the invention must be useful, novel and non-obvious. Unit packaging can certainly be useful. It is hard, however to see how taking a current product and just putting it in single use packaging is novel. Also, it would be hard to get past the non-obvious objection. I am not a lawyer, but my opinion is unless there is something unique about the packaging then this isn't patentable. Now if you come up with some clever way of packaging that hasn't been done before, we can reconsider.